# com_content—get associated article in right language

Tags: articles, language

I have a template, where would like to print the content of an article, what is working quite nice so far, using this code:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/models');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel');
$article = $model->getItem($aid);
$terms = empty($article->fulltext) ? $article->introtext : $article->fulltext;
```

So basically, I have the article's id and load it, **BUT** that throws an error if the current language differs from the language of the article. Unfortunately, I cannot »translate« the article ID, so I need to find a way, to get the right article based on the current language.

Fortunately, there are the associations I can use for that Job (image below).

[image: associations view]

So now my Question:

How can I load the associated Article?

n.b.:
I already had a look at the database, and I found the associations table, but I just hope that there is already some code I could use!

Thanks in Ahead!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `JLanguageAssociations::getAssociations`. [This function](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JLanguageAssociations.html) will return an array containing associated items. You can also check if if the language filter Items Associations parameter is enabled using `JLanguageAssociations::isEnabled();`.

Here's an example from `ROOT/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php`:

```
// Load associated content items
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$assoc = JLanguageAssociations::isEnabled();

if ($assoc)
{
    $item->associations = array();

    if ($item->id != null)
    {
        $associations = JLanguageAssociations::getAssociations('com_content', '#__content', 'com_content.item', $item->id);

        foreach ($associations as $tag => $association)
        {
            $item->associations[$tag] = $association->id;
        }
    }
}

return $item;
```

**Resources**:

- https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JLanguageAssociations.html
- http://asikart.com/docs/japi31/Joomla-Libraries/Language/JLanguageAssociations.html

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 1):

`components/com_content/helpers/association.php`

has a class `ContentHelperAssociation` and function `getAssociations($id = 0, $view = null)` you could probably use.